# How can some USB chargers produce larger total amperage than others?

Tags: power-supply, usb

From a quick survey of wall-mounted USB chargers with more than one USB port, it seems that the total amperage provided, for a given number of ports can vary significantly.
For instance, I saw 2-port chargers producing either 2.4A or 1.2A in total.

What is the difference, in terms of build quality and components, between chargers with the same number of ports but with different power?

Comment: Higher ampacity components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference, in terms of build quality and components, between chargers with the same number of ports but with different power?

Build quality is independent of power output in the range you are discussing.

The double-the-current power supply will deliver double the power as Power = V x I and V is the same in both cases (or should be).  (Nominally 1.2A x 5V = 6 Watt and 2.4A x 5V = 12 Watt.

The 12W supply is designed to produce a higher wattage output. That may seem obvious but may not be.   If frequency of switching is the same this involves

- About 2x the mean input current
- About 2x the peak input current

In resistive areas of the circuit power is proportional to I^2R so doubling current MAY double power dissipation.

Assume that all components are sized to be just-about-right for their tasks
In practice this is often not true - convenience and minimal cost differences between differently rated components and economies of scale and stocking convenience often results in a part being used which exceeds requirements. eg 1N4001...7 diodes used to be the industry standard through hole 1A low frequency power diode of choice. A 1N4001 diode is rated at 1A, 50V. A 1N4007 is rated at 1A, 1000V. the whole ...2 3 4 5 6 range in between exists BUT in practice you MAY almost always only ever see 1N4001, 1N4003 and 1N4007. I'd never use 1N4001 and a 1N4007 MAY be cheaper than a 1N4003. In days of yore I'd just stock 1N4007 and never need to choose.

But, assume that all components are sized to be just-about-right for their tasks

The higher input current and power will require

- Higher current rated switching transistor(s) or ICs.
- Double current rated diodes in AC mains bridge and in high frequency output diode(s) or if synchronous rectification is used, more capable MOSFET synchronous rectifier FET.
- High frequency transformer core able to handle double the saturation current so morecore material and thicker wire.
- Carried to extremes, greater copper area in tracks, better cooling, ...
- Higher ripple current capacitors.

In practice the differences in a 1.2A and 2.4A supply will be small or absent in many cases.

If a switching MOSFET is used it MAY be the same.

If an IC with an integrated high voltage switch is used it will probably be more highly power rated as cost and power tend to be more correlated than for MOSFETS.

And more ... . As power levels get up there are more differences. eg a 10A and 20A supply will almost certainlyt use different diodes and MOSFETS and transformer core size will probably be substantially different and ... .

Comment: @MatteoS, basically it's about larger components rather than ones with higher "purity" or "precision".  If you want a car to go faster you put a bigger engine (made of bigger pieces) rather than making the metal more pure.

Answer (score 3):

Cost and quality of components. A 2.4A supply *should* cost more than a 1.2A supply. However, the 2.4A supply *might* be less expensive or the same cost, if the 1.2A supply was made in fewer numbers, due to economy of scale. Also, a 2.4A supply might cost less because it is made without regard to safety or adherence to standards.

Comment: That's what I suspected. But what constitutes better quality (translating into higher ampacity)? Is it purity of metals, type of plastics, precision of soldering?

Comment: Well consider a humble resistor. You can get 1/4W or 1/2W versions. The 1/2W version can handle more power, but it's larger physically. So if you need to handle more power, you can opt for the larger one. If you are size-constrained, you opt for the smaller one. The USB chargers are both probably SMPS, but the higher current one will probably have higher-rated diodes and a switching IC, transformer, etc. I wouldn't consider "precision" of soldering to affect current capacity, that's just safety/quality in general.

Comment: Not only the economy of scale, but also the economy of demand; if the market won't bear a higher price for 2.4A supplies than for 1.2A supplies, then the price for 2.4A supplies will be the same as for 1.2A. The justification for building 2.4A supplies is simply that money can still be made building & marketing them, and there will be some niche market demand that moves them but wouldn't move the 1.2A version. Ya sells everything ya can. 8)

Answer (score 1):

In short, most usb chargers are simple switching regulators, typically a diode, an inductor, a pair of caps and some resistors, controlled by a single IC. Most usb chargers vary very little from the ICs reference design. As a production goal of these cheap mass produced parts is low part count and production costs, only the bare minimum parts needed are used.

So the only difference between chargers of different capacities is the wattage of the passive parts, and the IC. The IC provides the switching, courtesy of an internal mosfet. As new ics are created with higher amperage capacity, new chargers are created.

Case in point. Older *1 Amp* chargers are made using the mc39026 (part number from memory??). Except the mc39026 has a limit of 750mA using the internal mosfet, and often the current setting resistor is not the max so the charger actually limits to 700mA instead.

Newer 2.1A+1A chargers have a 5A IC, though there might be a lower current limiting resistor, or the passives may not withstand that much power through them. The 2.1A and 1A limits are artificially limited by the usb/apple charging resistors on the D+/D- lines, signaling to the phone at which rate they should pull power, not at what rate the charger can supply at.